# does the static keyword protect variables in #included files?

Tags: c, linker

Let's say I'm writing a library of functions, and each function makes use of a global array to perform its duties. I don't want to expose that array to non library code, so I declare it as `static` like so:

library.h:

```
void function1();
void function2();
```

library.c:

```
#include "library.h"
static int arr[ARBITRARY_SIZE];
void function1() {...} // both of these
void function2() {...} // make use arr
```

If I now want to use this library in my code, I would `#include "library.c"` at the top of my code.

If I understand correctly, `#include` simply copies and pastes in place the contents of the `#include`ed file. If this is the case, the user's code would itself contain the static definition of `arr`. Given that, how would I, as the author of the library, protect my library variables? If this is not the case, please correct me about what `#include` does!

Comment: You don't put the actual definitions of `function1` and `function2` in the .h file  (they go in the .c file) and so you don't need `arr` in the .h either.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question. If whatever .c file that implements the library functions includes the .h and the user code includes the .c file, isn't the user code still declaring the static variable itself?

Comment: User code includes the .h (not the .c) and so never sees `arr` (but it does need to link with the .o produced from the .c)

Comment: You don't `#include` C files, just header files.

Comment: To use the functions from a `.c` file, you link with the corresponding `.o` file.

Answer (score 1):

`static` keyword doesn't protect the memory used by a variable, you can pass out of a function (with visibility of it) a reference to the variable so the variable is accessible out of the block where it is defined.  Then the calling code can use that reference to modify it as desired.

`static` serves two purposes:

- inside a block in a function body, it states that: despite the variable has visibility only in the inside of the block where it is defined, its life is all the program life (it is not created/destroyed when the program enters/exist the definition block)
- outside a block, it gives local file visibility (the variable name is exposed nowhere out of the definition compilation unit).  But that doesn't imply that there's no accessability to that global chunk of memory.  You can, if you have a pointer reference pointing to it, still modify it as you want.

`#include` just text includes the include file contents verbatim in the compilation flow, so everything declared `static` in the include file has visibility in the including file (after the point of inclussion), and locally in every compilation unit that also includes the header file.  But all definitions of it are different and independent, and they don't refer to the same variable (as they are local definitions in different compilation units), as it happens if you name two local variables of different blocks (even when nesting the blocks) with the same name, they are different variables.

Answer (score 0):

> If I now want to use this library in my code, I would `#include "library.c"` at the top of my code.

That will only work if you use this library in a single source file.

As soon as you add `foo.c` and `bar.c` which both `#include "library.c"` and try to link them together, you would get a multiply-defined `function1` and `function2` symbol error (because each of `foo.o` and `bar.o` will now provide their own separate definitions.

You *could* fix this by making the functions static as well: `static void function1() { ... }`, etc. but this *not* how people usually use libraries, because that method causes long compile times and larger than necessary executable. In addition, if you are using this method, you *don't need* the `library.h` file *at all*.

Instead, what people *usually* do is compile `library.c` into `library.o`, `#include "library.h"` at the top of their source files, then link everything together.

> I don't want to expose that array to non library code, so I declare it as static like so:

*That* is a valid thing to do, and achieves your purpose (so long as you `#include "library.h"` and not `library.c`).

Note that using global arrays (as well as most other globals) makes code harder to reason about, and causes additional difficulties when making code thread-safe, and thus it's best to use globals very sparingly.